# How to cut prefix of string with 'sed'?

Tags: sed

Consider the following lines:

```
prefix1.value[TAB]someString
prefix2.anotherVal[TAB]anotherString
val[TAB]String
pref.stuff[TAB]stuff
dontTouch[TAB]stuff
```

I would like to have the result

```
value[TAB]someString
anotherVal[TAB]anotherString
val[TAB]String
stuff[TAB]stuff
dontTouch[TAB]stuff
```

So I want to cut the `prefix.` if there is one. Regular expressions work in the way that the first match is the longest so I was not able to create a working program. Is it possible to do this task with a single `sed` program?

My solution that is not working as it should:
`sed 's/^[^\t\.]*\.\?\([^\t\.]\+\)\t\(.*\)/\1\t\2/'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches the prefix alone, and replaces it by an empty string.

```
sed 's/^[^\t\.]*\.//'
```

Comment: oh my god, yesterday I was playing for hours with that... :) I still can't believe that this didn't occur to me, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this if there is only one dot possibe:

```
sed -e 's/^.*\.//' file
```

Answer (score 1):

if until first dot

```
sed 's/^[^.]*\.//' YourFile
```

if until last dot

```
se 's/.*\.//' YourFile
```

up to you to define your prefixe type